# gparted increase sdb1 from sdb2 free space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to resize my Linux partition that is not large enough (sda1, 20 Gb) using my data partition (sda2, 450 Gb).

I resized my data partition to create an unallocated space at the begining of sda2 but for an unknown reason I cannot increase sda1 using this space. How can I resize sda1 using this unallocated space?

[image]

**Edit** I followed @muclux anwser until step 4. But I can't do the step 5, because the partition sda2 is resizable but not movable.

[image]

Comment: You should just be able to move start of extended partition right. Normally that would not be possible with standard partitions as space would have to be on right also. And then the unallocated is moved out of the extended partition and you should be able to expand sda1. But why is sda1 so full. I use 25GB for my / and my 16.04 install now uses 12GB. I do regularly house clean and have moved some normally hidden larger folders from /home to my data partition.

Comment: `usr/` use 60% of the disk. `usr/share`and `usr/lib` are almost 100% of `usr/` disk usage.

Comment: Your extended partition sda2 is a container for all the logical partitions. Can you not resize from left or start entry? Of unallocated at beginning of extended partition it should work.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning: This answer does not work (see point 5). So you should try to do what is proposed in the comment by @oldfred.**

You can't resize /dev/sda1 immediately because the extended partition /dev/sda2 is adjacent to it. So you have to:

1. backup your data !!
2. move /dev/sda5 to the left to fill the unallocated space
3. move /dev/sda6 to the left (immediately after /dev/sda5)
4. resize the extended partition /dev/sda2 so that you get an unallocated space at the right end
5. **I'm sorry, this doesn't work as I have learnt [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802326/how-can-i-move-my-extended-swap-partition)**
   *move the extended partition to the right*
6. extend /dev/sda1
7. done!

Comment: Thanks, I went throught to steps 1 to 4 but I can't achieve step 5 because sdb2 is resizable but not movable. I edited the initial question

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't try it myself as I had no disk to play with.  See my edited answer.